# SSRS text parameter tied to SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have a report with two parameters. Both those parameters have a datatype of "text". I am having an issue passing the desired value to these parameters from SQL because the variables that represent those parameters in SQL cannot be text due to variables not being able to be "text" datatypes in SQL now. The variables right now are "datetime" datatypes. I tried using some other text like datatype in SQL such as nvarchar, nchar, char, varchar etc. but none of those solved my problem. I am wondering if there is a way that I can get the desired data passed to SSRS without changing the parameter date type in SSRS to date/time?

Here is a snippet of the code I am working with:

```
DECLARE @CBFCycleStart as datetime
DECLARE @CBFCycleEnd as datetime

SET @CBFCycleStart =
(SELECT TOP 1 [CycleStartedOn]         
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC) 

SET @CBFCycleEnd = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [CycleEndedOn] FROM 
[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] 
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the value of the parameters from SQL"?

Comment: My stored procedure datatypes passing to the SSRS parameters is what I meant, if that makes more sense.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.  I suspect you are probably mis-using the word "passing" but I don't know.  You haven't given enough information.   Keep in mind that none of us has your report and give us enough information to fully reproduce the issue from scratch.

Comment: I have a stored procedure that pulls data from a SQL table. My stored procedure variables that I mentioned contain the data it pulls from the SQL tables. I then take those values in the variables and want to pass them to the parameters in SSRS. The variables in SQL are datetime and the SSRS parameters are text. Hopefully this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: Show sample data from the SQL query and also expected parameter values desired.

Comment: The data the stored procedure is pulling is a date and time. The parameter value desired is a date and time as well.

Comment: What are your parameters you are passing from SSRS to SQL? The only variables in the SQL above are `@CBFCycleStart` and `@CBFCycleEnd`, which aren't parameters (as they are declared in the SQL) and are a `datetime` (not a string type for the SSRS `text` type). Where are your `varchar` parameters being referenced in the queries? You also set the values of those varirables, so they can't be parameters from SSRS (as what would be the point of passing a value to be overwritten).

Comment: The parameters in SSRS that I need to represent the data pulled from the stored procedure is Phase Start and Phase End. Both Phase Start and Phase End are "text" parameters. I am asking if there is a way to essentially keep the Phase Start and Phase End parameters a "text" and change the variable datatypes in my SQL stored procedure, if that makes sense. I need the variables in SQL to align with the text parameters in SSRS.

Comment: *"I need the variables in SQL to align with the text parameters in SSRS."* what does that even mean? how do you "align" text to a date? Align means "place or arrange (things) in a straight line.", how do you arrange text to be placed in a straight line to a date?

Comment: By align I mean "be the same" or "equal each other".

Comment: Can the user change those parameter values? If not, then why have them as parameters? Just declare them in the stored proc to get the dataset for the report.

Comment: I cannot change anything with the parameters, those must remain text and the exact way they are now... I need to only make changes in my SQL stored procedure. Preferably, to a text to equal the text parameter in SSRS.

Comment: Its quite clear from the answers and your responses that you have not given enough info here. All the suggestions so far make sense (to me at least). Can I suggest you post more info, including the `1.` main dataset query used to fetch the data final result data. `2.` Report parameter setup. `3.` Error messages instead of "It does not work". `4.` Any tests you have done such as manually typing in dates into the report parameters and if that worked or not, `5.` what format the date/string parameter is designed to accept and samples of such strings.

Comment: would help if you show some sample data as well

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datetime to String, like:

```
DECLARE @CBFCycleStart nvarchar(50);
SET CBFCycleStart=CONVERT(nvarchar(50), (SELECT TOP 1 [CycleStartedOn]         
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC), 120);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to set report parameters from the result set of a stored procedure.

You are almost there, add one more line to your SP.

```
DECLARE @CBFCycleStart as datetime
DECLARE @CBFCycleEnd as datetime

SET @CBFCycleStart =
(SELECT TOP 1 [CycleStartedOn]         
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC) 

SET @CBFCycleEnd = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [CycleEndedOn] FROM 
[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] 
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC)

**select @CBFCycleStart as CBFCycleStart  , @CBFCycleEnd as CBFCycleEnd**
```

name this dataset getStartAndEnd

This will give you a dataset with one row.

Now go to your parameters and set the values as defaults from this dataset getStartAndEnd

**Additional Note:**

I think you can rewrite your SP to this:

```
select CBFCycleStart = MAX([CycleStartedOn])
     , CBFCycleEnd  = MAX(CycleEndedOn)       
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1'
```

Comment: That comment is not helpful. This is exactly how you set parameters in SSRS from SQL.

Comment: Sorry Keith. I tried that and it did not seem to resolve my issue... Thank you for the feedback.