# Converting datetime to varchar in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a stored procedure that is referencing column name's `CycleStartedOn` and `CycleEndedOn`. Both of those columns are `datetime` datatypes. My goal is to convert them to a `varchar(MAX)`. I have variables `@CBFCycleStart` and `@CBFCycleEnd` holding those values. The code I have compiles but I am unsure if I am doing this incorrectly or if there is a more efficient and better way to achieve this goal. Here is the code I am working with:

```
DECLARE @CBFCycleStart as varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @CBFCycleEnd as varchar(MAX)

SELECT   
 @CBFCycleStart = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleStartedOn], 120) FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC)
 ,@CBFCycleEnd = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleEndedOn], 120) FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC)


 DECLARE @tblReports TABLE
(    
    CBFCycleStart varchar(MAX)
    ,CBFCycleEnd varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @tblReports
(    
    CBFCycleStart 
    ,CBFCycleEnd 
)

Values
(   
    @CBFCycleStart
    ,@CBFCycleEnd
)

SELECT * FROM @tblReports

END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS text parameter tied to SQL variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953807/ssrs-text-parameter-tied-to-sql-variable)

Comment: Why you need intermediate variables if the goal is @tblReports ? Are they used elsewhere in the proc?

Comment: I use "@CBFCycleStart" and "@CBFCycleEnd" in a separate SSRS report. The variables help with my SSRS report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it a bit like this:

```
DECLARE @tblReports TABLE
(    
    CBFCycleStart varchar(MAX)
    , CBFCycleEnd varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @tblReports
(    
    CBFCycleStart 
    , CBFCycleEnd 
)

SELECT TOP 1
    CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleStartedOn], 120)
    , CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleEndedOn], 120)
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1'
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC

SELECT * FROM @tblReports
```

It also provides a little more certainty that you're always selecting from the same row.

**Edit**

If you need the variables after the `INSERT`, you could use:

```
DECLARE @CBFCycleStart as varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @CBFCycleEnd as varchar(MAX)

SELECT TOP 1
    @CBFCycleStart = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleStartedOn], 120)
    , @CBFCycleEnd = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleEndedOn], 120)
FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT]
WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1'
ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC

DECLARE @tblReports TABLE
(    
    CBFCycleStart varchar(MAX)
    , CBFCycleEnd varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @tblReports
(    
    CBFCycleStart 
    , CBFCycleEnd 
)

VALUES
(
    @CBFCycleStart
    , @CBFCycleEnd
)

SELECT * FROM @tblReports
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spare one select as both select the same row

```
SELECT TOP 1  @CBFCycleStart = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleStartedOn], 120) 
 ,@CBFCycleEnd = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), [CycleEndedOn], 120) 
 FROM [IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] 
 WHERE [CycleComplete] = '1' 
 ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC;
```